# global_planner changing parameters

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-hydro, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I'd like to change the following parameters in the global_planner hydro-devel package to **false** to use the A* algorithme:

**~/use_dijkstra (bool, default: true)

If true, use dijkstra's algorithm. Otherwise, A*.**

But I can't find the file in which I must make changes !!

EDIT:

File: move_base.launch.xml:

```
<!-- 
    ROS navigation stack with velocity smoother and safety (reactive) controller
-->
<launch>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/velocity_smoother.launch.xml"/>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/safety_controller.launch.xml"/>
  <arg name="odom_topic" default="odom" />
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
  <param name="base_global_planner" value="global_planner/GlobalPlanner" />              
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

There's no Planner.yaml or global_planner.yaml that contains the parameter that I'd like to change !

Can someone help me please.

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210414/global_planner-changing-parameters/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on 2015-06-02**:
This is the relevant tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Within the move_base namespace:

```
 <param name="GlobalPlanner/use_dijkstra " value="true" />
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0